# C# creating a custom NumberFormatInfo to display "Free" when a currency value is $0.00

Tags: c#, .net, currency, tostring, iformatprovider

I need to display a currency in my ASP.NET MVC application but when the currency is 0 I would like it to display "Free" (localized of course!) instead of $0.00.

So when I have something like this...

```
Decimal priceFree = 0.00;
Decimal priceNotFree = 100.00;

priceFree.ToString("C");
priceNotFree.ToString("C");
```

The output is
"$0.00"
"$100.00"

I would like it to be
"Free"
"$100.00"

I imagine I can use the .ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider) method to accomplish this but I'm not sure how to go about it.  Obvious I want to reuse as much of the NumberFormatInfo as possible and only override it when the input is 0.  In that case I can simple return a localized resource that contains my "Free" string.

So how do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: I'd recommend introducing a Money/Currency class instead of passing around decimals. That would allow you to do this much more easily and because Currency has a lot more going on with it than decimals do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the easiest way to go would be an extension method:

```
public static string ToPriceString(this decimal value) 
{
    if (value <= 0m) 
        return "Free"; // Your localized resource
    else 
        return value.ToString("C");
}
```

If you want to go with the `IFormatProvider`, [there is a good example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.getformat.aspx).

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of extension methods is my primary reason.  But in this case it might be a poor excuse.  Simplest solution is often the best and in this case the Extension method is very simple.

Comment: BTW: Any chance you can provide more information about value <= 0m.  I'm not super family with the 0m syntax.  Thanks!

Comment: Ok...  so <a href="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75(VS.71).aspx">decimal</a> explains the m.  I was curious what value <= 0m would return for a negative number.  But I guess in this case there is no such thing as a negative price.

Comment: Even though it represents a price, a decimal can be negative. If you used a custom class for currency instead, you could disallow that.

Answer (score 17):

Use

```
.ToString("$###.00;;Free")
```

Comment: +1, nice.  For anyone else who hasn't seen this before: [The ";" Section Separator
](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SectionSeparator).

Comment: Seems interesting.  Can you provide a reference or perhaps describe your answer a bit more?  I'm not exactly sure whats going on there with the format string.It doesn't seem very Localization friendly.

Comment: Thanks to adrift for the reference.  I like the idea but unless you can make it localization friendly I think the extension method is the way to go for this one.

Comment: @Justin: You can localize the format string, just as easily as your "free" string... (or compose it from a localized "Free" string).

Comment: Hi Reed.  I do agree I could localize the rules but that requires knowledge of how other cultures localize their currency.  Since this behavior is built into the framework using .ToString("C") I'd favour it.  I am a fan of this particular solution its a neat one and great to have in the toolbelt!

Answer (score 2):

How about an extension method:

```
public static string FreeString(this decimal dec)
{
   if(dec == 0M)
   {
      return "Free";
   }
   else
   {
      return dec.ToString("C");
   }
}
```

Then

```
priceFree.FreeString();
priceNotFree.FreeString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a custom IFormatProvider and passing it each time, how about  this:

```
 public static class MyFormatter
    {
        public static string ToFreeString(this decimal d)
        {
            return d == 0 ? "Free" : d.ToString("d");
        }
    }
```