# How to use NumberFormatInfo to remove parenthesis for negative values

Tags: c#, .net, globalization, iformatprovider

We're currently using the following for creating US dollar values in our web application:

```
string.Format("{0:C0}", dollarValue );
```

In this example, if dollarValue is 145, then we'll see: $145. If it is -145, then we'll see ($145) rather than -$145. Note that for us, dollarValue is a double, but it could be any number-type. I think.

Anyway, what I want is for it to be either $145 or -$145.

Now, according to my research, it might be possible to do this using the NumberFormatInfo class. I can't figure out how to use it, and I can't find any valid example. I did see this question here: [C# creating a custom NumberFormatInfo to display "Free" when a currency value is $0.00](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866796/c-sharp-creating-a-custom-numberformatinfo-to-display-free-when-a-currency-val) but the example from MSDN linked to from this question seems a bit different from what I really want to do.

I realize, I will need to do something of the following:

```
double dollarValue = -145d;
string myMoney = dollarValue.ToString( "C0", someIFormatProvider );
```

where someIFormatProvider is likely of type NumberFormatInfo. Now, what I've done is this:

```
NumberFormatInfo ni = new NumberformatInfo();
ni.CurrencyNegativePattern = 1; // The value 1 should mean not to use parenthesis
string myMoney = dollarValue.ToString( "C0", ni );
```

...and I get an "Instance is Read-Only" exception. While the "documentation" for the CurrencyNegativePattern property says you can SET and GET the value, apparently, you can't. Also, NumberFormatInfo is a sealed class. I can't easily create a new class based off it and override the value.

I'm at a loss as to how to deal with this. Right now, my workaround is to just negate my negative value and have a positive result that I do the `string.Format(...)` again. Yes, I realize there is no negative sign in front of this, but, of course, that's easily resolved by adding a "-" in front of the result as needed.

Would someone be able to provide me with a working example of how to effectively use the NumbefFormatInfo class correctly in this situation? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the error comes from setting the CurrencyNegativePattern of a NumberFormatInfo instance? I've seen this Read-Only exception, but it is raised from  trying to modify the CurrentUICulture properties?

Comment: The code works for me (after fixing the case on `NumberformatInfo`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double dollarValue = -145d;
 System.Globalization.CultureInfo modCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
 string mymoney = dollarValue.ToString("C", modCulture);
          MessageBox.Show(mymoney);
```

If your Operating System current culture is en-US then you dont need the following line

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo modCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
```

The code will be

```
double dollarValue = -145d;
string mymoney = dollarValue.ToString("C");
```

and If you want to do with NumberFormatInfo

```
double dollarValue = -145d; 
System.Globalization.CultureInfo modCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
     NumberFormatInfo number = modCulture.NumberFormat;
     string mymoney = dollarValue.ToString("C", number);
```

another way

```
double dollarValue = -145d;
System.Globalization.CultureInfo modCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
NumberFormatInfo number = modCulture.NumberFormat;
string mymoney = dollarValue.ToString(String.Format("C",number));
Console.WriteLine(mymoney);
```

Comment: And here's [the doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencynegativepattern.aspx).

Comment: I tried this answer in a console app for testing and the result was ($145). If I used "C" instead of "0:C0", for the format, I got ($145.00).

Comment: Okay, the NumberFormatInfo answer you provided works if I set the CurrencyNegativePattern to 1. This also correctly sets the currency symbol which isn't properly set if I don't use the culture. Good job.

Comment: @MMK thank you for your answer. I think there is a missing part in your code, this is, the part where you specify "number.CurrencyNegativePattern = 1" in order to remove the parenthesis. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11015234/2816119

Answer (score 13):

You can make a clone of the `NumberFormat` property in the `CurrentCulture` (this will ensure that you keep the correct currency symbol if you globalize your application).  After that, just set the [`CurrencyNegativePattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencynegativepattern.aspx) property to the desired value and pass in your `NumberFormatInfo` in the `double.ToString()` function, like so:

```
NumberFormatInfo noParens = (NumberFormatInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.Clone();
noParens.CurrencyNegativePattern = 1;
double dollarValue = -145d;
string output = dollarValue.ToString("C0", noParens); // outputs -$145
```

Comment: Interesting. Thank you, this worked. I am glad to see I wasn't too far off on the overall implementation. I just didn't know I needed to clone it.

Comment: This will also allow you to use the current culture, so you don't have to hard-code it to "en-US" in case you end up globalizing your web application.

Answer (score 4):

Try this...

```
string.Format( "{0:$#.;-$#.}", -145 )
```

or

```
dollarValue.ToString("$#.;-$#.")
```

Comment: You need to swap the `$` and the `-`.

Comment: And of course, `string.Format("{0:$#.;-$#.}", dollarValue)` is equivalent to `dollarValue.ToString("$#.;-$#.")` in the same way as `string.Format("{0:C0}", dollarValue)` is equivalent to `dollarValue.ToString("C0")`.

Comment: @Jeppe format fixed....thanks for the catch...and I like your second option a bit better...changed to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

'instance is ReadOnly'  means you have a read-only instance of `NumberFormatInfo`.  You can get a writable instance by cloning a read-only instance:

```
NumberFormatInfo writeable = (NumberFormatInfo) ni.Clone();
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the CurrencyNegativePattern can't be assign? I've tried with this code:

```
double dollarValue = -145d;
System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo ni = new System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo();
ni.CurrencyNegativePattern = 1;
dropDownList.Items.Add(new ListItem(dollarValue.ToString("C0", ni)));
```

and it's success.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure you remain in a "US-context" I'd do something like this:

```
double val = -145d;
NumberFormatInfo nfi = new CultureInfo("en-US").NumberFormat;
nfi.CurrencyNegativePattern = 1;
val.ToString("C0", nfi).Dump();
```

The `Dump` comes from LinqPad, which displays `-$145` as a result.

The error you are getting feels like it comes from you getting your `NumberFormatInfo` something like this:

```
NumberFormatInfo nfi = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat;
```

In which case I'd replace by something like this:

```
NumberFormatInfo nfi = (NumberFormatInfo)Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.Clone();
```