# C# how to convert a double to string with decimal and thousand

Tags: format, double, decimal

Hi want to convert in C# a double 1123$ to 1.123,00 (one thousand and two decimal).

How can I do that?

thanks

Comment: Are these $ values, ie you want to print dollars, but with mainland european separators. If I was doing a  mixture like that, I'd bve looking at constructing a NumberFormatInfo. See this for further details, it's about negatives, but the concept holds. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11014878/how-to-use-numberformatinfo-to-remove-parenthesis-for-negative-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use this

```
YourDecimal.ToString("N",new CultureInfo("nl-NL")) // this will result in 1.000,00 for example
YourDecimal.ToString("N",new CultureInfo("en-US")) // this will result in 1,000.00 for example
```

Or you could set the culture in Web.Config if you're using ASP.NET.

You can also pick any other culture if that matches the dot and comma delimiter ofcourse. These are just examples.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var text = money.ToString("N0",
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de"));
```

Comment: cuz they use . for the separator

Comment: A point, Guy did $ though, hmmm, suspect this might end up being a bit more complex than it initially appears.

Answer (score 1):

```
Double x=1123.0;    
x.ToString("N",new CultureInfo("nl-NL"))
```