# C#: how to check manually my current CurrencyNegativePattern format?

Tags: c#, localization, currency

The problem is I am setting a textblock control's text as to a negative value(ex: -$5). But depending upon the CurrencyNegativePattern it is showing ($5).
I want to know is there any manual way to change this property.

Comment: See [this MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencynegativepattern(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11014878/how-to-use-numberformatinfo-to-remove-parenthesis-for-negative-values)

Comment: @stuartd the question seems to more concentrated on changing the string, i am interested in changing the property, currencyNegativePatter of my current culture, can i do that?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000509/how-to-change-currentculture-at-runtime) shows how to change the CurrentCulture at runtime

Comment: @stuartd ...that question helped thanks

Comment: yes i did that..that is working programmatically but i wanted to check what the value was manually, just like i can check the regional settings in control panel